# Htaccess laravel friendly urls

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, seo, friendly-url

How can i make this dynamic url:

https://example.com/s?location=Brasov&source=ds&min_price=41&max_price=3098

into this:

https://example.com/s/Brasov&source=ds&min_price=41&max_price=3098

using htaccess? My website is build on Laravel framework.

Comment: Just throwing this out there but you realize that is still not considered a friendly url right? In fact, I think it's a syntactically incorrect url...

Comment: Well basically i only need the s?location=City part to be part of the friendly url

Comment: I would kindly ask you to help me with an direct answer to my question. I know there are several related topics and already tried several answers. nothing worked so far and thats why i posted the question. Thank you!